# get parents of a users

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

i want to know is there any possibility to get the User and all his parents if we suppose we have a reflexive relation between users , each user has a parent user and childrens maybe .

here is my User entity class .

```
<?php
namespace Lab\DemoBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Lab\DemoBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * OneToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="parent")
     * @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $childrens;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can i confirm this question, are you looking to get this users parent and then that users parent etc, of all of this one users parents?

Comment: something like [this](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not

```
public function hasParent()
{
  return $this->parent !== null;
}

public function getAncestry()
{
  $ancestors = array();
  $member = $this;

  while ($member->hasParent())
  {
    $member = $member->getParent();
    $ancestors[] = $member;
  }

  return $ancestors;
}
```

Comment: I don't agree this method, while lazy loading with reflexive functions can be the worst thing for your website performance.

Comment: Nonsense, Yann. You can't measure the performance of a car just by inspecting one piece such as the alternator. Just the same way you can't measure the performance of a "website" by inspecting a single  method. I'm not saying low-level implementations are beyond scrutiny, but the point of this answer is not that the ancestry is being lazy-loaded (that is easily changed) but rather just to present a rough algorithm for determining the ancestry period. And on that point, this is not an expensive algorithm - it's O(n) for the depth of the user in the tree.

Comment: Okay, I don't want to spend my time to try to convince you. You method will work, I'm sure of it. This is (I think) the fastest implementation of Abdou's need. I just say that when you deal with reflexive methods and Doctrine relations, you may be aware that there is a potential danger for your website's performance. But hopefully, there is always possible optimizations.

Comment: Yes Yann , i know its just a temporary solution , and it will cause  a potential danger of performance , but what can you suggest as implementation of a secure methode to work with reflexive methods ?

Comment: Not sure that there is a perfect way to deal with that kind of things. But you may think about creating your own queries when dealing with these objects.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `xurshid29`, you should have a look to the [Tree Doctrine Extension](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) which allow you to deal with parents and children.